# Partitioning a grid in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

For school I had to try and make "Game of Life" using MPI. And one of the questions was: "Would OpenMP be a better choice?" Now, I was thinking how I should implement this in OpenMP and I could not get past the problem of how to partition my grid such that communication is minimized as I did in MPI. As far as I know OpenMP does all partitioning by itself. I could not really find something on the internet. So, to summarize, the question is how would one go about partitioning a grid, in which points need information of its neighbors, such that communication is minized.

Comment: One doesn't partition the grid.  OpenMP is a *shared memory* approach to parallel computing.  One writes code in which each thread has access to the grid.  If the program uses `p` threads then each thread is responsible for `1/p-th` of the grid, and the programmer takes care to avoid *data races*, especially at the borders between the parts of the grid 'owned' by neighbouring threads.  Communication is (generally) not explicit, it's effected by shared access to data.

Comment: Ah, oké. That's what I thought, but in this situation it seems quite risky to trust that OpenMP will put neighbouring threads on the same process.

Comment: *it seems quite risky to trust that OpenMP will put neighbouring threads on the same process*  But an OpenMP program is only one process: multiple threads, single process.

Comment: But how do you achieve the desired speedup if only 1 process is used?